# Finding the mean from the variance

Tags: probability, matlab, means, chi-squared

Is it possible to find the mean from the variance?

Here is the problem:

> Supposed that in 3-D $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, P)$ where $P = 10000 * I_3$. What is the radius of a sphere centered at $\mu$ having a 95% containment probability?

While I understand that the radius of the sphere can be found by:
$$R=\sigma*\sqrt{Y} = ||X - \mu||$$
where $Y = (X - \mu)^T P^{-1} (X- \mu)$

Finding that can be done by a nice clean little MATLAB command:

```
sqrt(chi2inv(0.95,mu))
```

However, I'm not sure how to obtain $\mu$ in this case. Is it possible to derive $\mu$ from $\sigma$? Or am I overthinking this and this must be solve at a more abstract level? Extra points if there is a nice MATLAB way to go about solving it - especially since I can use the above command to get the radius without hand writing the math.

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: Is $X$ supposed to have a multivariate normal distribution with covariance matrix $1000I_3$?

Comment: If so, you cannot say anything about the mean just from the covariance matrix, but I think you do not need to know the mean to answer this question

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I thought that could be assumed. I'm not sure how to add the tilde in Latex. It was supposed to look like X ~ n($\mu$,P) if that makes sense?

Comment: How would you not need the mean? Would you elaborate some?

Comment: If I show you a basketball and ask you whether its [size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_(ball)#Sizes) is 7 (men), 6 (women), 5 or 4 (youth), you may not actually need to know its precise location to calculate this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your analogy?

Comment: The question is asking you for the radius of a sphere centred at the same place as your multivariate normal distribution.  So where that point actually is should not affect the size of the sphere

Comment: ah, okay, I see - that makes sense. So, is there a concrete way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are not even using `chi2inv` correctly. The second argument is the degrees of freedom of the chi-squared distribution that you want to use, not $\mu$.

You want to find $R$ such that $P(\|X - \mu\|^2 \le R^2) = 0.95$.
Since $X \sim N(\mu, 10000 I_3)$ we have $Z \sim N(0, I_3)$ where $Z := (X - \mu) / 100$.
Thus we want $R$ such that $P(\|Z\|^2 \le (R / 100)^2) = 0.95$. Since $\|Z\|^2$ follows a chi-squared distribution with $3$ degrees of freedom, you can find the $95\%$ quantile using `chi2inv(0.95, 3)` and set it equal to $(R/100)^2$ and solve for $R$.

Comment: Ah, so the second parameter to chi2inv is the degrees of freedom. So, as another random example. if you wanted to find the 80% critical value for a chi-squared distribution with 2 degrees of freedom, you would use chi2inv(0.80, 2)?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand where you got 100 in your use of $Z$?

Comment: @BillyThorton If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2 I_3)$ then $X - \mu \sim N(0, \sigma^2 I_3)$ and $(X - \mu) / \sigma \sim N(0, I_3)$.

Comment: How did you know that 10000 is $\sigma^2$ and not just $\sigma$?
Using your methodology, I wrote this line in MATLAB:
`syms R; radius = double(solve((R/100)^2 == sqrt(chi2inv(0.95,3)), R))`
Which gives me $167$. Does that seem like a fair answer? It seems a bit large?